# Glitchy screen when trying to install Ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb, usb-installation, visual-artifacts

The USB is brand new. i launched Ubuntu in safe graphics mode and the screen goes like this and then goes completely black.

[image]

I downloaded Rufus and Ubuntu 20.04 from their websites, then with Rufus copied Ubuntu to the USB then I cleaned the disk (Shift  while resetting computer -> solve problem -> system symbol -> and emptied the disk) then I turned off and on the computer and selected safe graphics from the GNU GRUB menu, I launched safe graphics because I was following a tutorial.

I turned off the PC and tried the no safe graphics mode and it works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: What were the EXACT steps you took to make the boot USB? Why did you launch in safe graphics mode? You have not given all the info.

Comment: Hello david sorry for the lack of details i downloades rufus and ubuntu 20.04 from their websites then with rufus copied ubuntu to the usb then i cleaned the disk (shift while reseting computer>solve problem>system simbol>and emptied the disk)then i turned off and on the computer and selected safe graphics from the GNU GRUB menu, i launched safe graphics because i was following a tutorial. sorry if you dont understand english isn’t my native language